# How to use Rails with Mongoid and not PostgreSQL or SQLite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

Added Mongoid but got:

```
LoadError:
Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter.
```

Removed database.yml and got:

```
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
```

Saved empty database.yml and got:

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified:
'test' database is not configured. Available: []
```

Rails 5.2.2

Answer (score 1):

If it is fresh install use

```
rails new app --skip-active-record
```

if you already created an App with rails, which has active-record(mysql or sqlite3)
use this link:

[Rails with Mongoid](https://medium.com/aviabird/guide-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04-9ed292dc53f6)

Also remove

> active records

lines from

> application.rb

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord is a library that works only with relational databases. If you want to use MongoDB with mongoid, you don't need ActiveRecord. Remove any mention of AR and relational DBs from the application code, config and Gemfile. If you're stating from scratch, use `rails new myapp --skip-active-record`

See also: https://gorails.com/guides/setting-up-rails-4-with-mongodb-and-mongoid (related to Rails 4, but should help).